# Generic measurement variable in Swift

Tags: swift, generics, measurement

I have this code

```
public class DoubleSensor: ObservableObject {
    private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private(set) var sensor: any VEntity
    
    @Published public var state: doubleState = DefaultState.forDouble()
    
    public init(withSensor sensor: any VEntity) {
        self.sensor = sensor

    }
    
    private func updateData(fromState newState: doubleState) async {
        self.state = newState
    }
}

public final class TemperatureSensor: DoubleSensor {
    
    public var measurement: Measurement<UnitTemperature> {
        return Measurement(value: state.value, unit: .celsius)
    }
    
    public override init(withSensor sensor: any VEntity) {
        super.init(withSensor: sensor)
    }
}

public final class PercentageSensor: DoubleSensor {
    
    public var measurement: Measurement<UnitPercentage> {
        return Measurement(value: state.value, unit: UnitPercentage.percentage)
    }
    
    public override init(withSensor sensor: any VEntity) {
        super.init(withSensor: sensor)
    }
}

public final class EnergySensor: DoubleSensor {
    
    public var measurement: Measurement<UnitEnergy> {
        return Measurement(value: state.value, unit: .wattHours)
    }
    
    public override init(withSensor sensor: any VEntity) {
        super.init(withSensor: sensor)
    }
}
```

As you can see I have 3 class inheriting from `DoubleSensor` class (a small version of it). All of inheriting classes have a measurement variable specific to a measurement unit.
How can I create a generic class instead specific ones?

I can create something like

```
public final class MeasurementSensor<T: Dimension>: DoubleSensor {

    public var measurement: Measurement<T> {
        return Measurement(value: state.value, unit: ???)
    }
    
    public override init(withSensor sensor: any VEntity) {
        super.init(withSensor: sensor)
    }

}
```

but I don't know how to set the unit value

Edit:

Thanks to [Dávid Pásztor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4667835/d%c3%a1vid-p%c3%a1sztor) to suggesting me edits to improve the question:

`VEntity` is a protocol defined as

```
public protocol VEntity: Hashable, Equatable {
    var domain: String { get }
    var entityId: String { get }
    var entityName: String { get }
    var notificationName: NSNotification.Name { get }
}
```

`doubleState` is a typealias defined as

```
public typealias doubleState   = EntityState<Double, GenericAttributes>
```

where `EntityState` is an object representing an entity state with two generics properties: S (value) and A (attributes), but I don't think its definition (not small) is useful in this context

and `GeneriAttribute` is

```
public struct GenericAttributes: VAttribute {
    public let commonName: String
}
```

*are your DoubleSensor subclasses only supposed to work with a hardcoded unit value? or should they work with any value of the same type?*

My goal is to get rid of multiple inheriting classes and create just one that will contain a measurement of given unit.
Ex:

```
let temperatureSensor: MeasurementSensor = MeasurementSensor(withSensor: sensor01, andUnit: UnitTemperature, measuringIn: .celsius)
let energySensor: MeasurementSensor = MeasurementSensor(withSensor: sensor02, andUnit: UnitEnergy, measuringIn: .kilowattHours)
```

This is just pseudocode to give an idea of final result. I hope now question is more clear.

Edit 2:

Suggested by [Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141234/alexander) (thanks) I think we can cut off all irrelevant stuff keeping only what we need, so we can use this class

```
public final class MeasurementSensor {
    var value: Double
    
    public var measurement: Measurement<UnitEnergy> {
        return Measurement(value: value, unit: .kilowattHours)
    }
    
    init(value: Double) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

as example, but keeping that pseudocode above as a final result

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic. What's `VEntity`? What's `doubleState`? Also, are your `DoubleSensor` subclasses only supposed to work with a hardcoded unit value? Or should they work with any value of the same type? Currently your `TemperatureSensor` for instance only works with `.celsius` - is it also supposed to work with other `UnitTemperature` instances?

Comment: @DávidPásztor I think it would be even better to edit out all the irrelevant stuff like the uses of `VEntity`, `DoubleState`, `ObservedObject`/`@Published`

Comment: @Orkysh Can you please simplify this down to a single focused copy-pastable block? I want to help here, but I have to hunt down all these broken references to various types/values. Like where did `UnitPercentage` and `UnitEnergy.wattHours` come from?

Comment: This question is only getting more confusing for each edit…

Comment: @Orkysh Please don't treat your question as a changelog of edits. This site already tracks edit history (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77988024/revisions)), so if anybody cares for the backstory, that's how they can find it. Please integrate all your appended edits into one whole question with a coherent narrative.

Comment: oh ok @Alexander, sorry for the confusion. I saw this changelog style in other posts so I thought it was correct. I'll keep it in mind!

Comment: @Orkysh It can be useful for calling out large changes in direction (e.g. that might make the existing answers seem out-of-place with the newly edited question), but it shouldn't be used for edits like "simplify the entire thing and make the initial question clear". Just simplify the entire thing and make it more clear. Nobody needs the complex and unclear original :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a generic class where the measurement unit is of a certain type, you simply need to make your class generic over the `Dimension` type and inject the actual unit you want to use when creating a new instance.

```
final class MeasurementSensor<UnitType: Dimension> {
  var value: Double
  var unit: UnitType

  var measurement: Measurement<UnitType> {
    return Measurement(value: value, unit: unit)
  }

  init(value: Double, unit: UnitType) {
    self.value = value
    self.unit = unit
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
let kwhSensor = MeasurementSensor(value: 0, unit: UnitEnergy.kilowattHours)
let celsiusSensor = MeasurementSensor(value: 0, unit: UnitTemperature.celsius)
```